# run a single State monadic action recursively

Tags: haskell

I have a single monadic action called `step` that I would like to run recursively until it returns a `Nothing` value. The below code works, but I'm calling `runState` on every step. The solution I'm looking for would build up within the state monad then call `runState` once at the end.

I know my use of `Maybe` here screams "transformer", but I'm trying to get it to work without a transformer first.

```
testFn :: Int -> Maybe Int
testFn i = if i > 5 then Nothing else Just i

step :: State Int (Maybe Int)
step = do
    i <- get
    let i' = testFn i
    put $ maybe i (1 +) i'
    return i'

go :: Int -> Int -> Maybe Int
go s a = case runState step s of 
    (Nothing, _)  -> Just a
    (Just a', s') -> go s' a'
```

repl:

```
> go 0 0
Just 5
```

Comment: So what exactly o you want to obtain when it returns `Nothing`? The state?

Comment: the last value that wasn't Nothing. Or the input value if the first step returns Nothing.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can write a modifier that transforms a `a -> State s (Maybe a)` to a `a -> State s a`:

```
repeatM :: Monad m => (a -> m (Maybe a)) -> a -> m a
repeatM f = g
    where g x = f x >>= maybe (pure x) g
```

We can thus create a function with:

```
repeatStep :: Int -> State Int Int
repeatStep = repeatM (const step)
```

Then `go` is just:

```
go :: Int -> Int -> (Int, Int)
go s a = runState (repeatStep a) s
```

Here the first item of the 2-tuple is the `Int` that is the last `Just …` output before it outputs `Nothing`. The second item of 2-tuple is the state in that case.

and then our `go` thus returns:

```
Prelude Control.Monad.State> go 0 0
(5,6)
```

Comment: I think the way you wrote `repeatStep` it has the type `Int -> State Int Int`

Comment: @codenoodle: aarrghhh, yes. Thanks for spotting this.